# How to check the logged in user in multiple guard?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, guard

I am using laravel 10. I have 2 guards. One is admin and another is manager . The Auth only authenticate the default one so in the controller construction I have set

```
 public function __construct(){
        \Config::set('auth.defaults.guard','admin');
    }

 public function __construct(){
        \Config::set('auth.defaults.guard','manager');
    }
```

Now I have to check the user to verify if it's admin or manager guard but if I check the guard name its says null. `auth()->guard('guard_name')->user()->name;` I dont know how can I get the guard name to authenticate!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the guard in the `constructor` you can define directly the guard when authenticating :

```
Auth::guard('guard_name')->attempt(...);

//or

Auth::guard('guard_name')->login($user);
```

Then if you want to check if the user is authenticated with specific guard you can use the `check()` method in `Auth` Facade.

```
Auth::guard('guard_name')->check(); // it will return true if there is authenticated user using the given auth guard.
```

Comment: If I define directly then it generates error because the default guard is web so it can't be found. If I set this in default section then the manager  guard becomes disable because only one guard is default and can be active. Thats why I had to put this in construction function.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an idea to solve this issue. When the query successfully executed, setting another value as admin or manager based on their controller and passing the data as array with token.